# How do I check a string for one or more symbols

Tags: string, go

I'm struggling to find a method of checking to see if a string contains one or more symbols like the following: `#}{&*"(£)` While it's fairly trivial to make a check for one or more of these symbols I'm not looking to build and maintain a list or dictionary of possible entries. Is there a way I can check to see if a string contains one or more of *any* non standard symbol in go preferably using the standard library?

Specifically I'm looking to detect anything that isn't `a-zA-Z0-9` which for the basis of my question would be counted as a non standard symbol.

Comment: Define "non-standard symbol?" Anything but `a-zA-Z0-9`? Is a period (`.`) a standard symbol? What about other common punctuation `",'?!`?

Comment: @AdamSmith Precisely and yes, I was about to edit in that maybe something that looks for anything that's not an English letter or number could be the key.

Comment: If you make a string that contains all the runes you consider "standard", you can use [`strings.ContainsAny`](https://godoc.org/strings#ContainsAny) and negate the result.

Comment: I misread your previous comment, I'll give that a go quickly in a playground.

Comment: You wrote the character class you want right in the question, why not just drop that in a regex?

Comment: Do you know of https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.MatchString ?

Comment: Okay going to give the two methods a go and write small benchmark, thanks guys. If someone wants the answer and could create a small playground that'd be good, otherwise I'll write it myself and post it soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Go, write a simple function. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func isStandard(s string) bool {
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        switch b := s[i]; {
        case b >= 'a' && b <= 'z':
            continue
        case b >= 'A' && b <= 'Z':
            continue
        case b >= '0' && b <= '9':
            continue
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(isStandard(`ABCabc123`))
    fmt.Println(isStandard(`#}{&*"(£)`))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Y2KjDcHSupH

Output:

```
true
false
```

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Switch statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements)
>
> "Switch" statements provide multi-way execution. An expression or type
>   specifier is compared to the "cases" inside the "switch" to determine
>   which branch to execute.
>
> Expression switches
>
> In an expression switch, the switch expression is evaluated and the
>   case expressions, which need not be constants, are evaluated
>   left-to-right and top-to-bottom; the first one that equals the switch
>   expression triggers execution of the statements of the associated
>   case; the other cases are skipped. If no case matches and there is a
>   "default" case, its statements are executed. There can be at most one
>   default case and it may appear anywhere in the "switch" statement.
>
> The switch expression may be preceded by a simple statement, which
>   executes before the expression is evaluated.
>
> [Fallthrough statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Fallthrough_statements)
>
> A "fallthrough" statement transfers control to the first statement of
>   the next case clause in an expression "switch" statement. It may be
>   used only as the final non-empty statement in such a clause.

---

```
switch b := s[i]; {
    // ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
switch b := s[i]; true {
    // ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
{
    b := s[i]
    switch true {
        // ...
    } 
}
```

The simple statement `b := s[i]` declares `b` to be a `switch { }` statement block local variable.

The case expresions are evaluated and compared to `true`. If none are true, the `default` is taken.

Go, unlike C, requires explicit `fallthrough`.

ASCII is a subset of Unicode UTF-8. Since the standard characters are all ASCII, we can simply compare bytes.

---

Here is a simple benchmark.

Output:

```
$ go test standard_test.go -bench=. -benchmem
BenchmarkPeterSO-8    200000000       8.10 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkJubobs-8      10000000     222 ns/op       0 B/op    0 allocs/op
$
```

`standard_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "testing"
)

func isStandard(s string) bool {
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        switch b := s[i]; {
        case b >= 'a' && b <= 'z':
            continue
        case b >= 'A' && b <= 'Z':
            continue
        case b >= '0' && b <= '9':
            continue
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func BenchmarkPeterSO(b *testing.B) {
    std := `ABCabc123`
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        isStandard(std)
    }
}

var (
    whitelist  = "A-Za-z0-9"
    disallowed = regexp.MustCompile("[^" + whitelist + " ]+")
)

func IsValid(s string) bool {
    return !disallowed.MatchString(s)
}

func BenchmarkJubobs(b *testing.B) {
    std := `ABCabc123`
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        IsValid(std)
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like your answer for simplicity, could you elaborate how the switch case statements work here?

Comment: @lix: See my revised answer.

Comment: I never really thought about the actual workings of `switch` that you outlined. Thanks for the tidbit.

Comment: As expected it's blazing fast, I ended up implementing this version instead on my app. I also learnt a fair bit about characters and strings in go.

Comment: Those benchmarks are a nice touch! I won't mind if the OP ends up accepting your answer rather than mine.

Answer (score 3):

Since the whitelist can easily be defined as a regexp, use [`regexp.MatchString`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.MatchString):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

var (
    whitelist  = "A-Za-z0-9"
    disallowed = regexp.MustCompile(fmt.Sprintf("[^%s]+", whitelist))
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(IsValid("foobar007"))
    fmt.Println(IsValid("foo%bar&007"))
}

func IsValid(s string) bool {
    return !disallowed.MatchString(s)
}
```

([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ledwkw7xSm4))

Comment: Yeah this was close to what I was writing but I was struggling a bit with the must compile, thanks jubobs.